# Transparent PayPal transfer to end user

Tags: asp.net, paypal

We’re currently working on a ASP.NET web project using Visual Studio 2010, and as a requirement we have to implement a mechanism that will transfer some amount of money from our business account to end-user PayPal account.

The authorized user should provide the PayPal email address only.

The precondition is to do all that staff without redirecting to PayPal web site, everything should be done in background.

Is there any solution to solve this?
Any information would be greatly appreciated.

PS
I’ve read a lot of official documentation, but still disappointed. There are too many APIs and services, can’t identify what exactly should be used.

Please help…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the Advanced PayPal Payment solution, you can do transparent payments from your website without redirecting to PayPal. This solution uses a web service to send payment. When I used it some time ago it was really simple to set up and you get a sandbox environment where you can experiment with it. You'll likely need a business account to be able to use this particular API.

[Here's an article that describes how to use it.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42894/Introduction-to-PayPal-for-C-ASP-NET-developers)

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. That helped me to get the right SDK. If anybody encountered the same difficulties, take a look at PayPal Adaptive Payments SDK, it should save your time and energy.

Comment: Do u have any Sample Code to Pay money from Merchant Paypal Account to Customers Paypal account? Please help..! See here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20088272/how-to-transfer-money-from-merchant-paypal-account-to-enduser-paypal-account-thr