# How to transfer Money from Merchant Paypal account to EndUser Paypal account through ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have a requirement to Transfer the Amount from `Paypal Merchant Account` to `End User Paypal account` in my `asp.net web application using C#`. Is it possible?

Here is the Scenario:

1. Consumers visits a website and want to sell some Products listed online on a website.
2. Login to website and choose the product to sell online via our website.
3. Website accepts(paypal information) & sends the Shipping information.
4. **After receiving the Product, the Payment is to be done from `Merchant Paypal Account` to `End Users Paypal account` via Web application.**

So, is there any `Paypal API` to transfer money from `Merchant Account` to `EndUser Paypal account`?

Is their any `SandBox` provided by `Paypal`?

Sample Code in ASp.net?
Please recommend the requirements, suggestions to do..!

Help Appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

there are a number of options available when it comes to transferring funds from a merchant account to another account (sending money).

1. MassPay API --> This is a robust solution you can use to send funds from one merchant to up to 250 recipients per call. This can be done via an API request and via the PayPal Account itself by uploading a CSV file.

   More info:
   Documentation: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/mass-pay/gs_MassPay/
   Sample Code: http://paypal.github.io/#merchant --> you'll find a masspay sample within the SDK
2. Adaptive Payments API - Implicit Payments --> With adaptive payments, you do have the option of sending "Implicit Payments" basically, when the sender account is the same account that is associated with the API Username, PayPal does not require an explicit approval from the sender (hence the "implicit")

   Documentation: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/#id094MB0Q0T5Z

   Samples: http://paypal.github.io/#adaptive-payments
3. Payments Pro - Credit API --> You can send funds directly to a customers credit card using the "DoNonReferencedCredit" API method

See: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoNonReferencedCredit_API_Operation_NVP/
Samples: refer to the Merchant SDK linked in 1.

Out of the top of my head, these would be the available PayPal product options.

Comment: hi @PayPal_Martin thanks for taking efforts..! Which method will you suggest me to pay Multiple customers from my Web Application without moving to Paypal interface? is it Possible without paypal interface transfer money from one paypal to other using asp.net?

Comment: Hi Shekar, all of these products offer a fully documented API and SDK - so it really depends on your specific use case and would probably blow the constraints of this forum. However, when you send to multiple customers, Masspay probably offers the best fees structure.

Comment: I can't be the only one who can't find a good example of Implicit Payments anywhere, can I? Everywhere I look, I see examples of preapproval and the other types, but implicit payments are nowhere to be found. It can't be that unpopular to be doing automated payments, can it?

Answer (score 0):

download code in this link
asp.net code for paypal
http://www.codeguru.com/dbfiles/get_file/Use_of_the_PayPal_VB_NET_src.zip?id=13851&lbl=USE_OF_THE_PAYPAL_VB_NET_SRC_ZIP

Comment: may i know why this post is being Down Voted? It seems like some people if don't know the solution just go on pressing the Down Vote button without any reason..!

Comment: hello @sagivasan, above i have mentioned that the payment is done from Merchants account(website owner) to the Customers paypal account..! this is NOT what i am looking for so sorry..!